# Spring MVC model attribute value not displaying

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, model, attributes

I am having a problem getting some of my model attributes to display.

Here is part of the data I am setting

```
            spd.email = "testaddr@ser.net";
    spd.birthMonth = "11";
    spd.birthDay = "12";
    spd.birthYear = "2013";
```

Here is where I add things to the view. sessionID & email are simple Strings. spd is defined above;

```
           ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("signup");
             mav.addObject("sessionID",sessionID);
             mav.addObject("email", email);              
             mav.addObject("SignupPageData",spd);
```

Here are the lines in the jsp

```
            <p>email from spd  ${signuppagedata.email}  </p>
                <p>email ${email} ></p>
                  <p>sessionID ${sessionID} ></p>
```

both of the simple Strings email & sessionID print fine. signuppagedata.email does not display.
What am I doing incorrectly ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the model attribute names are case sensitive. Change this

```
mav.addObject("SignupPageData",spd);
```

to

```
mav.addObject("signupPageData",spd);
```